# Compare date value to current date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

How can I compare the date in a row to a current date, so that if it's greater than today the next steps in my process need to be executed?

Answer (score 16):

## Short answer

Assuming that you want to compare a date in the cell A1 with the current date, use the following formula:

```
=A1>TODAY()
```

The above will return TRUE if the value of the cell A1 is the greater than the current date.

## Explanation

In Google Sheets the comparison functions and operators could be used with dates if they are properly formatted.

By properly formatted, I mean that spreadsheet engine is able to interpret the cell value as a date. For Google Sheets a date is a serialized number that has assigned a date format. One alternative among others to check if a value is a number is to use [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en).

Comparison functions:

- [EQ](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093593?hl=en) Equivalent to the `=` operator.
- [GT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098240?hl=en) Equivalent to the `>` operator.
- [GTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093975?hl=en) Equivalent to the `>=` operator.
- [LT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093596?hl=en)  Equivalent to the `<` operator.
- [LTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093976?hl=en) Equivalent to the `<=` operator.